# `Vagrant Up` not working in Pycharm

Tags: vagrant, pycharm

I have been trying to set up Vagrant with my project in PyCharm, but I've run into a problem. In `Preferences > Vagrant` I have set the path to the Vagrant executable (obtained via `which vagrant`), and I have set the instance folder to the project root. There is one Vagrant Box in the list on that same page (`precise32 (virtualbox)`)

A Vagrantfile exists in my project, but when I go to `Tools > Vagrant > Up`, a file dialog appears, and regardless of what I select next (e.g. Vagrantfile, `vagrant` executable), nothing happens (i.e. the `Run` window doesn't open).

I've been looking at [different](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/initializing-vagrant-boxes.html) [pages](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/vagrant.html) in the [Pycharm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/vagrant-2.html) but it has brought me no closer to an answer.

How can I get `vagrant up` working in Pycharm?

*Note: I am using PyCharm 2.7 on Mac 10.7.5, if that helps*

Comment: Do provision not up if you already have the box configured

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. 
Go to **Preferences** --> **Tools** --> **Vagrant** and set your *Vagrant executable* to something like: `/usr/local/bin/vagrant`. In my case it looked like that somehow this settings was changed to `vagrant`. After I set the absolute path all worked fine again.